# How can i add trial period when update subscription plan?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am currently using Cashier (Stripe) to the Plan subscription. I am currently using `$this->subscription->swapAndInvoice($this->selected->stripe_plan_id);` like this to change the subscription plan. Here i want to know how can i add trial period (7days) when i change subscription plan?
If anyone have any idea? please give your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be an optional parameter directly in the `swapAndInvoice` function, but you should be able to update the subscription immediately before the swap to [add a trial](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing#extending-trials):

```
$subscription->extendTrial(
  now()->addDays(7)
);
```

The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing#changing-plans) say that if a trial exists, it will be preserved:

> If the user is on trial, the trial period will be maintained.